# Task Scheduler in windows10 - just created task is not listed in active tasks

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks

I created it in the following way:

- Open Task Scheduler from the start menu.
- Clicked on "Create Basic Task" to create a new task and click Next.
- Entered Name for the task
- Answer when to Trigger the task.
- At Action section, select "Start a program" and click Next.
- I selected shutdown.exe file from C:/Windows/System32
- -s in arguments box
- Clicked Next.
- Clicked Finish to create the task.

It is not listed in active tasks.

Pressing refresh changes nothing.

Where I can find this task? Do I need to activate it somehow?

It is appearing in `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks`

I tried opening the Task Scheduler with administrator privileges, nothing changed.

`Get-ScheduledTask` in powershell lists it:

```
TaskPath                                       TaskName                          State
--------                                       --------                          -----
\                                              Adobe Acrobat Update Task         Ready
\                                              OneDrive Reporting Task-S-1-5-... Ready
\                                              OneDrive Standalone Update Tas... Ready
\                                              shutdown                          Ready
\                                              Shutdown test                     Ready
\                                              TEST                              Ready
\                                              TEST2                             Ready
(...)
```

It is listed in task library:

[image]

It is not listed in active tasks:

[image]

(typical Windows - there is a cron variant with fiddly GUIs that are half broken, manages to be worse than directly editing text files with no GUI)

Comment: Open Task Scheduler.  Left Side. See Task Scheduler Library. Expand that and expand all below that. Is your task anywhere there?

Comment: @John I went through this, but I could miss something - the list is extremely long. Are user defined tasks landing in some specific folder?

Comment: You need to work through each folder to see if your task was saved or not saved.

Comment: Open Powershell (preferably as admin), run the cmdlet Get-ScheduledTask (or Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName YourTaskName). See if it is listed.

Comment: What is the output of Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName YourTaskName?

Comment: OK, I finally see it in the library - but not in active tasks.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio`TaskPath                                       TaskName                          State
--------                                       --------                          -----
\                                              shutdown                          Ready`

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio more readable form in question itself

Comment: So.. perhaps I am just tired *and being stupid* but if this task were ACTIVE, would the machine not be shutting down?  I believe that an ACTIVE task is one that is running and a SCHEDULED task is one that will become ACTIVE at the indicated trigger (in this case time).

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas There are "active tasks" and there is "Display all running tasks"

Comment: Thanks @reducingactivity :P  Guess I *was* being stupid.  Thanks for the clarification.